# How to search by method's fully qualified name in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I need to search by method's qualified name in Eclipse (Luna)

I've tried to find `myMethod` using qualified name (copied with right click > *Copy Qualified Name*) and then *Ctrl+V* in Eclipse's search box `myproject.core.services.MyClass.myMethod(P)`

this way:

[image: eclipseSearchBox]

The code is like this:

```
public class MyClass extends AnotherClass {
    @Override
    public void myMethod(P p) {
        // code
    }
}
```

When I search as shown in the above image, I'm getting as search result the method from the parent class (AnotherClass)

I want MyClass's overridden method as search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of** limiting the query to **qualified references**, choose in the *Limit To* section ***Declaration*** to find the method declaration.

The match location *Qualified references* is for static methods. For example, in the following main method, there are one non-qualified and two qualified references to the `com.example.Foo.foo()` method:

```
package com.example;
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(); // non-qualified reference
        Foo.foo(); // qualified reference
        com.example.Foo.foo(); // (full) qualified reference
    }

    static void foo() {}

}
```